# Does increasing the mass in a SHM decrease the max velocity of the mass?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

If a mass is attached to a block and the block suddenly gains mass, will the max velocity decrease?

Answer (score 2):

$$v_{\text{max}} = ω A$$

For a mass-spring oscillator, maximum velocity equals angular frequency
times amplitude.  If the system is horizontal, then the equilibrium position will not change, but the angular frequency will decrease.

If the change is when the mass is at maximum velocity, at zero displacement, then velocity will have no reason to decrease at that position.  The angular frequency will decrease but the maximum velocity will not.  Amplitude will increase to compensate.

If the change is when the mass is at maximum amplitude and zero velocity, then the maximum amplitude will not change.  Because angular velocity will decrease while amplitude remains the same, maximum velocity will decrease.

For a vertical oscillator, increasing the mass will move the equilibrium location.  The situation will be more complex.  Still, some cases will reduce the maximum velocity and some will not.

Comment: Do you think [this](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-mass-m-attached-to-a-horizontal-spring-executes-shm-with-amplitude-a/) answer is wrong? @ken

Answer (score 0):

For a spring mass oscillator, the maximum velocity,

$$v_{\textrm{max}} = A\omega$$

where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac km}$. Therefore
$$v_{\textrm{max}} = A\sqrt{\frac km}.$$

Hence if the mass $m$ increases, the maximum velocity decreases.